# image name and content type of the image

Tags: asp.net, image

how to get the image name and content type in mvc application i am using the input type file control of Html on my page .please help me with useful answers.

Thanks,
ritz

Comment: Ritz, if an answer has been helpful, please mark the answer as accepted.  If it's not helpful, add a comment to get more information.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/03/file-uploads-with-mvc-framework.html.  I presume that you are trying to upload an image in ASP.NET MVC.  The linked article should get you most of the way there.  The image content type isn't immediately available, but just assume it to be image/jpeg or image/png depending on the extension of the file name.